# SQL Trigger Inserting from Multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute a query within a SQL trigger.

I have 4 tables `A, B, C, D`. Table A is a lookup list and contains roughly 1400 rows of data. Table B are values being input through an HMI with a timestamp. Table C is the table where my values are intended to go. Table D is a list of multipliers to use to multiply values from table A to table B (I am only using one multiplier from table D at the moment).

When a user inputs data into table B, that should trigger the procedure to get the values that were inserted (including the itemnumber) and relate the itemnumber to table A and use table D to multiply a few things together to send values to Table C. If I only input 3 rows of data in table B for example, I should only get three rows of data in table C. I am merely using table A to match the item number and get some data. But for some reason  I am inserting way more records than intended, over 1600 rows.

Table D multipliers have a timestamp that does not match or have any correlation with any other table. So I am using a timestamp and selecting  the multipliers that are closest to the timestamp from table B (some multipliers will change throughout time and I need a historical multiplier to correctly multiply the right things together)

Your help is most appreciated. Thank you.

```
Insert into TableC( ItemNumber, Cases, [Description], [Type], Wic, Elc, TotalElc, LbsPerCase, TotalLbs, PeopleRequired, ScheduleHours, Rated, Capacity, [TimeStamp])
   Select 
      b.ItemNumber, b.CaseCount, a.ItemDescription, a.DivisionCode, a.workcenter, 
      a.LaborPercase as ELC, b.CaseCount * a.LaborPerCase * d.IpCg, 
      a.LbsPerCase, a.LaborPerCase * b.CaseCount as TotalLbs, 
      a.PersonReqd, b.Schedulehours, a.PoundRating, 
      b.ScheduleHours * a.PoundRating as Capactity, b.shift, GETDATE() 
   from 
      TableA  a, TableB b, TableD
   Where 
      a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber 
      and d.IpCG < b.TimeStamp 
      and b.CasesCount > 0
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced by the *proper* ANSI JOIN syntax with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: So after reading the link, all of my combining of tables and not using joins are really skewing my query. I will work on using joins in this query. Thanks

Comment: You said this is a trigger but you only reference persistent tables. Where are the references to INSERTED or DELETED virtual tables?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I left them out. I just was testing the functionality of the query itself

Answer (score 0):

You do not reference the inserted or deleted tables that are available only in the trigger, so of course you are returning more records tha you need in your query.

When first writing a trigger, what I do is create a temp table called #inserted (and/or #deleted) and populate it with several records. It should match the design of the table that the trigger will be on. It is important to make your temp table have several input records that might meet the various criteria that affect your query (so in your caseyou want some where the case count would be 0 and some where it would not for instance) and that would be typical of data inserted into the table or updated init. SQL server triggers operate on sets of data, so this also ensures that your trigger can properly handle multiple record uiinserts or updates. A properly written trigger would have test cases you need to test to make sure everything happens correctly, your #inserted table should include records that meet all those test cases.

Then write the query in a transaction  (and roll it back while you are testing) joining to #inserted. If you are doing an insert with a select, only write the select part until you get that right, then add the insert. For testing, write a select from the table you are inserting to in order to see the data you inserted before you rollback.

Once you get everything working, change the #inserted references to inserted, remove any testing code and of course the rollback (possibly the whole transaction depednig on what you are doing.) and add the drop and create trigger part of the code. Now you can test you trigger as a trigger, but you are in good shape becasue you know that it is likely to work from your earlier testing.